# Pattern for building a functional based plugin architecture

Tags: .net, design-patterns, functional-programming, system.reactive

I am investigating how to develop a plugin framework for a project and Rx seems like a good fit for what i am trying to achieve. Ultimately, the project will be a set of plugins (modular functionality) that can be configured via xml to do different things. The requirements are as follows

1. Enforce a modular architecture even within a plugin. This encourages loose coupling and potentially minimizes complexity. This hopefully should make individual plugin functionality easier to model and test
2. Enforce immutability with respect to data to reduce complexity and ensure that state management within modules is kept to a minimum
3. Discourage manual thread creation by providing thread pool threads to do work within modules wherever possible

In my mind, a plugin is essentially a data transformation entity (I'm trying to think functional here). This means a plugin either

- Takes in some data and transforms it in some way to produce new data (Not shown here)
- Generates data in itself and pushes it out to observers
- Takes in some data and does some work on the data without notifying outsiders

If you take the concept further, a plugin can consist of a number of all three types above.For example within a plugin you can have an IntGenerator module that generates some data to a ConsoleWorkUnit module etc. So what I am trying to model in the main function is the wiring that a plugin would have to do its work.

To that end, I have the following base classes using the Immutable nuget from Microsoft. What I am trying to achieve is to abstract away the Rx calls so they can be used in modules so the ultimate aim would be to wrap up calls to buffer etc in abstract classes that can be used to compose complex queries and modules. This way the code is a bit more self documenting than having to actually read all the code within a module to find out it subscribes to a buffer or window of type x etc.

```
public abstract class OutputBase<TOutput> : SendOutputBase<TOutput>
{
    public abstract void Work();
}

public interface IBufferedBase<TOutput>
{
    void Work(IList<ImmutableList<Data<TOutput>>> list);
}

public abstract class BufferedWorkBase<TInput> : IBufferedBase<TInput>
{
    public abstract void Work(IList<ImmutableList<Data<TInput>>> input);
}
public abstract class SendOutputBase<TOutput>
{
    private readonly ReplaySubject<ImmutableList<Data<TOutput>>> _outputNotifier;
    private readonly IObservable<ImmutableList<Data<TOutput>>> _observable;

    protected SendOutputBase()
    {
        _outputNotifier = new ReplaySubject<ImmutableList<Data<TOutput>>>(10);
        _observable  =  _outputNotifier.SubscribeOn(ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance);
        _observable = _outputNotifier.ObserveOn(ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance);
    }

    protected void SetOutputTo(ImmutableList<Data<TOutput>> output)
    {
        _outputNotifier.OnNext(output);
    }

    public void ConnectOutputTo(IWorkBase<TOutput> unit)
    {
        _observable.Subscribe(unit.Work);
    }

    public void BufferOutputTo(int count, IBufferedBase<TOutput> unit)
    {
        _observable.Buffer(count).Subscribe(unit.Work);
    }
}

public abstract class WorkBase<TInput> : IWorkBase<TInput>
{
    public abstract void Work(ImmutableList<Data<TInput>> input);
}

public interface IWorkBase<TInput>
{
    void Work(ImmutableList<Data<TInput>> input);
}

public class Data<T>
{
    private readonly T _value;

    private Data(T value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public static Data<TData> Create<TData>(TData value)
    {
        return new Data<TData>(value);
    }

    public T Value { get { return _value; } }

}
```

These base classes are used to create three classes; one for generating some int data, one to print out the data when they occur and the last to buffer the data as it comes in and sum the values in threes.

```
public class IntGenerator : OutputBase<int>
{
    public override void Work()
    {
        var list = ImmutableList<Data<int>>.Empty;
        var builder = list.ToBuilder();
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            builder.Add(Data<int>.Create(i));
        }

        SetOutputTo(builder.ToImmutable());
    }
}

public class ConsoleWorkUnit : WorkBase<int>
{
    public override void Work(ImmutableList<Data<int>> input)
    {
        foreach (var data in input)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ConsoleWorkUnit printing {0}", data.Value);
        }
    }
}

public class SumPrinter : WorkBase<int>
{

    public override void Work(ImmutableList<Data<int>> input)
    {
        input.ToObservable().Buffer(2).Subscribe(PrintSum);
    }

    private void PrintSum(IList<Data<int>> obj)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Sum of {0}, {1} is {2} ", obj.First().Value,obj.Last().Value ,obj.Sum(x=>x.Value) );
    }
}
```

These are run in a main like this

```
        var intgen = new IntGenerator();
        var cons = new ConsoleWorkUnit();
        var sumPrinter = new SumPrinter();

        intgen.ConnectOutputTo(cons);
        intgen.BufferOutputTo(3,sumPrinter);

        Task.Factory.StartNew(intgen.Work);

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Is this architecture sound?

Comment: Rx has nothing at all to do with plugins, it's about processing streams of events. It won't find any plugins, won't load them and won't direct any calls to them. .NET includes the [Managed Extensibility Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this purpose. Sometimes IoC container are used to create simple plugin architectures.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, thanks for the lightning fast response! I have looked at MEF etc, and I think they are okay but not what I need. I already have the code for loading, distributing calls etc. What i am trying to do with my design is force plugins to be modular by intention and im just using Rx to replace events essentially. Rx is better than events in that it allows querying etc which i intend to harness in the abstract classes .Don't know if that's any clearer?

Comment: I would be inclined to play purely with Rx some more before you try to fit it in to this architecture. You still haven't understood the fluent nature of Rx. At the end of the day you're not publicly exposing any Rx interfaces, so that's good and that means your architecture stands or falls on its own merits. But Rx and/or functional programming isn't much of a feature here - you're really using it in a very basic way to provide the internal glue. I think you need to define the requirements of your architecture more and ignore the Rx in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are better off embracing `Rx` in your modules instead of hiding it away inside your base classes.  That route leads to re-implementing a subset of the Rx API on your own.  And then if a plugin uses `Rx` internally, you'll end up with wasted effort as that plugin essentially translates your non-Rx API into Rx API, when you could have just exposed the API directly.

The "Rx way" of doing this:

Generators (case 1) should expose (most likely *cold*) `IObservable<T>`:

```
interface IGenerator<T>
{
    // each subscription to this will create a new stream of data
    IObservable<T> Data { get; }
}

public class LongGenerator : IGenerator<long>
{
    IntGenerator()
    {
        // example that produces a new integer every second
        Data = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

        // something more complex...
        Data = Observable.Create(async (observer, token) =>
        {
            // infinitely poll some web service for the number
            while (!token.CancellationRequested())
            {
                var result = await _client.WebServiceCall(...);
                observer.OnNext(result.Value);
            }
        });
    }
    public IObservable<T> Data { get; private set; }
}
```

Consumers (case 3) should expose an `IObserver<T>`:

```
interface IConsumer<T>
{
    // Use IObserver<ImmutableList<T>> if you want to *force* them to receive buffered input
    // but why not let them do their own buffering if they need it?
    IObserver<T> Observer { get; }
}

public class ConsoleWork : IConsumer<int>, IObserver<int>
{
    public IObserver<T> Observer { get { return this; } }


    public void OnNext(int value) ...
    public void OnError(Exception e) ...
    public void OnComplete() ...
}
```

Transformers (case 2) should have a method that accepts an `IObservable<T>` and returns an `IObservable<U>`:

```
interface ITransform<T, U>
{
    IObservable<U> Transform(IObservable<T>);
}

public class StringTransform : ITransform<int, string>
{
    IObservable<string> Transform(IObservable<int> source)
    {
        return source.Select(i => "Hello " + i.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. I am still hesitant to force Rx down every ones throat at the moment. This is to replace a legacy plugin framework that exists and how Rx will play out in the long term is a concern for me. If the next new thing comes along , I want to be able to cleanly replace Rx with minimal rework to already existing code. Your solution is spot on though, I will keep experimenting and see whether there is a nice compromise between exposing Rx like you suggest and keeping the  rest of the framework as Rx agnostic as possible. Cheers

Comment: Keep in mind that both `IObservable` and `IObserver` interfaces are defined in corlib.  Technically anyone can use your API without ever using Rx--instead they could use whatever async library they prefer and just build a bridge to the required interfaces.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help @Brandon.I did not consider that, that settles it then :). Im going with your pattern with a little bit of tweaking